# How to re-enable screen dimming?

Tags: java, android

I needed to keep screen on while displaying my application so I disabled Dimming using this code :
`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

the problem is that when I close the application, dimming is still disabled
and I want to re-enable screen dimming  for power saving is there a code to reverse it ?

note my application has services working in background all the time,I think it's irrelevant as I put the code in an activity class;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the View function [setKeepScreenOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29). It's more friendly.

Comment: I tried to clear the flag
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Comment: but with no effect . you R right but I'm a beginner to android programming so I used this code as it is